# trying to identify text nodes with htmlagility pack

Tags: c#, .net, xml, html-agility-pack

I am trying to identify text nodes from an HTML text having a format like as below

sample text 1 :  `<strong>[Hot Water][Steam][Electric]</strong> Preheating Coil`

sample text 2 :  `<b><span>[Steam] [Natural Gas Fired] [Electric] [Steam to steam]</span></b><span> Humidifier</span><br>`

using the below code

```
public static string IdentifyHTMLTagsAndRemove(string htmlText)
{
    _ = htmlText ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(htmlText));

    var document = new HtmlDocument();
    document.LoadHtml(htmlText);
    var rootNode = document.DocumentNode;

    // get first and last text nodes
    var nonEmptyTextNodes = rootNode.SelectNodes("//text()[not(self::text())]") ?? new HtmlNodeCollection(null);

    //if (nonEmptyTextNodes.Count == 0)
    //{              
    //    return rootNode.OuterHtml;
    //}
    if (nonEmptyTextNodes.Count > 0)
    {
        var firstTextNode = nonEmptyTextNodes[0];
        var lastTextNode = nonEmptyTextNodes[^1];

        // get all br nodes in html string,
        var breakNodes = rootNode.SelectNodes("//br") ?? new HtmlNodeCollection(null);
        var lastTextNodeLengthIndex = lastTextNode.OuterStartIndex + lastTextNode.OuterLength;
        foreach (var breakNode in breakNodes)
        {
            if (breakNode == null)
                continue;

            // check index of br nodes against first and last text nodes
            // and remove br nodes that sit outside text nodes
            if (breakNode.OuterStartIndex <= firstTextNode.OuterStartIndex
                || breakNode.OuterStartIndex >= lastTextNodeLengthIndex)
            {
                breakNode.Remove();
            }
        }
    }
    return rootNode.OuterHtml;
}
```

But it is constantly failing here

> var nonEmptyTextNodes =
> rootNode.SelectNodes("//text()[not(self::text())]") ?? new
> HtmlNodeCollection(null);

and `nonEmptyTextNodes` giving count as zero, I am unsure where I am doing wrong with the above  code.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve with

```
//text()[not(self::text())]
```

It tries to select text()-nodes that are not text()-nodes. So nothing will be found. If you just use

```
//text()
```

Will select all text()-nodes

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Siebe's answer, I'd also like to point out an inefficiency in the code that trims start/end BR tags. If you look at the HtmlAgilityPack code for HtmlNode operations, you'll see that whenever nodes are removed, the SetChanged() method is called on the parent (and its parent, all the way up). The next time you check the start/end indexes of anything in the tree, they need to be recalculated. So this code could be made to run much faster if you instead just create a temporary list of all the nodes to be removed, then remove them after they've all been identified.

```
var lastTextNodeLengthIndex = lastTextNode.OuterStartIndex + lastTextNode.OuterLength;
var breakNodesToRemove = rootNode.SelectNodes("//br")?.Where(node => node.OuterStartIndex <= firstTextNode.OuterStartIndex || node.OuterStartIndex >= lastTextNodeLengthIndex).ToList();
breakNodesToRemove?.ForEach(a => a.Remove());
```

reference: https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/blob/master/src/HtmlAgilityPack.Shared/HtmlNode.cs